# Android: Failure delivering result, Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fileprovider

I am trying to use uCrop for cropping images and uploading to firebase. I want to allow the option of either using the camera or files for input.

```kotlin
val pickIntent = Intent()
        pickIntent.type = "image/*"
        pickIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
        val takePhotoIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        val pickTitle = "Select or take a new Picture"
        val chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickIntent, pickTitle)
        chooserIntent.putExtra(
            Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, arrayOf(takePhotoIntent)
        )
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
```

my `onActivityResult` function looks like this :

```kotlin
override fun onActivityResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        resultCode: Int,
        data: Intent?
    ): Unit {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (resultCode === Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode === REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
                var photoFile: File? = null
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile()
                    if(photoFile != null) Log.v("AFTER CREATE IMAGE FILE", "photoFILE " + photoFile.toString())
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        var photoUri: Uri =
                            FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, this.packageName, photoFile)
                        Log.v("AFTER FILE URI", "photoUri " + photoUri.toString())
                        startCrop(photoUri)
                    }

                } catch (ex: IOException) {
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

The null check for `photoFile` in the above code fails and I don't receive any log for that if statement.
However, I run into the following error for the lack of authority:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1888, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:25 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.gigforce.app/com.gigforce.app.modules.photoCrop.ui.main.PhotoCrop}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.gigforce.app
```

But I have following in my manifest:

```
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="{applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths">
            </meta-data>
        </provider>
```

and `file_paths.xml` look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Also, for some reason, the files are being saved in

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.gigforce.app/files/Pictures/IMG_20200318_192722_2465645043825713296.jpg
```

instead of the `.` defined in `file_paths.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, this.packageName, photoFile)
```

You are using `this.packageName` as your authority string.

Your actual authority string is:

```
android:authorities="{applicationId}.provider"
```

These do not match. So, instead, use:

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "${this.packageName}.provider", photoFile)
```

or:

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.provider", photoFile)
```

(the latter should be a bit faster)